# Netbeans/Glassfish - not connecting with jdbc using sun-resources.xml

Tags: mysql, netbeans, jdbc, glassfish

I'm trying to get a Netbeans/Glassfish Enterprise application to run locally on my pc (it is currently working in production). I've gotten as far as the login display, but when I try to log in, the app throws the following exception:

```
 SEVERE: "com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.login.common.LoginException: Login failed: javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: Failed file login for myloginname".
```

And the login servlet forwards to a login error page.

The web.xml in the "-web" project looks like this:

```
<resource-ref>
    <res-ref-name>jdbc/my_name_MySQL</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
</resource-ref>
```

There's also a persistence.xml set up as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="1.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="modCompJar-PU" transaction-type="JTA">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <jta-data-source>jdbc/my_name_MySQL</jta-data-source>
    <properties>
      <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect"/>
      <property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache" value="true"/>
      <property name="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache" value="true"/>
      <property name="hibernate.cache.provider_class" value="org.hibernate.cache.EhCacheProvider"/>
      <property name="hibernate.transaction.manager_lookup_class" value="org.hibernate.transaction.SunONETransactionManagerLookup"/>
      <property name="hibernate.query.factory_class" value="org.hibernate.hql.classic.ClassicQueryTranslatorFactory"/>
      <property name="hibernate.search.default.indexBase" value="/opt/index/webInput"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Finally, there's a sun-resources.xml, which looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE resources PUBLIC "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Application Server 9.0 Resource Definitions //EN" "http://www.sun.com/software/appserver/dtds/sun-resources_1_3.dtd">
<resources>
  <jdbc-resource enabled="true" jndi-name="jdbc/my_name_MySQL" object-type="user" pool-name="MyPool">
    <description/>
  </jdbc-resource>
  <jdbc-connection-pool allow-non-component-callers="false" associate-with-thread="false" connection-creation-retry-attempts="0" connection-creation-retry-interval-in-seconds="10" connection-leak-reclaim="false" connection-leak-timeout-in-seconds="0" connection-validation-method="auto-commit" datasource-classname="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" fail-all-connections="false" idle-timeout-in-seconds="300" is-connection-validation-required="false" is-isolation-level-guaranteed="true" lazy-connection-association="false" lazy-connection-enlistment="false" match-connections="false" max-connection-usage-count="0" max-pool-size="32" max-wait-time-in-millis="60000" name="MyPool" non-transactional-connections="false" pool-resize-quantity="2" res-type="javax.sql.DataSource" statement-timeout-in-seconds="-1" steady-pool-size="8" validate-atmost-once-period-in-seconds="0" wrap-jdbc-objects="false">
    <property name="URL" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:33306/mydatabsename?relaxAutoCommit=&quot;true&quot;"/>
    <property name="User" value="root"/>
  </jdbc-connection-pool>
</resources>
```

Note I've set up a tunnel via Putty to use a remote database, thus the "33306" for the mysql port instead of 3306.

I also changed Netbeans to point to the remote server's database, using the tunneled port. That works because the clicking on the "Database" node under the "Services" shows the same databases as exist on the remote server.

I know the login is correct because when I log in to the application running on the server, I get in, and they're both accessing the same database.

I also noticed there are some jdbc connection pools set up in "domain.xml" which refer to non-existent databases and ip addresses. The only valid database is the one shown above, in "sun-resources.xml".

How can I get this app to connect to the right database?